# Como faço para inserir um botão depois de uma listview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Olá, preciso inserir um botão logo após minha listview. Ou seja, quando acabar de deslizar minha listview terá um botão no final.

Estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.tipoMensal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    </ListView>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Enviar"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Mas ele não aparece no final.

Minha listView está sendo populada:

```
public List<AvaliacaoMensal> todosMensal() {
        List<AvaliacaoMensal> dados = new ArrayList<AvaliacaoMensal>();
    dados.add(new AvaliacaoMensal("As máquinas e equipamentos possuem selo de liberação por um líder Gerdau e está dentro do prazo de validade?", 'A', "Condição Fisica"));
```

Comment: É uma lista simples ou esta usando adapter customizado?

Comment: @acklay Adapter customizado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar Um RelativeLayout, alinhar o Button na parte inferior, fazer com que o ListView ocupe todo o espaço acima de Button, conforme abaixo:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.gerdaumanagement.gerdaumanagement.tipoMensal">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/botao"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</ListView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/botao"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Enviar"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Já tentei assim, mas ele fica sobre minha listview, queria que ele aparecesse só no final da listview. @David Carvalho

Comment: Há realmente necessidade de que seja feita dessa forma? Não é muito recomendável tendo em vista que caso a lista seja longa, o usuário tenha o trabalho de rolar a tela inúmeras vezes apenas para executar a ação de clique do botão. Caso realmente seja isso, o exemplo do Mystic será satisfatório.

Answer (score 1):

Como estas a usar `ListView`, você pode usar o método `addFooterView`, no qual adicionará uma `View` no rodapé de sua lista, como se fosse o ultimo item. Veja:

```
Button btnFooter = new Button(this);
btnFooter.setText("Botão Rodapé");
listview.addFooterView(btnFooter);
```

Outra opção caso você queria que esse botão seja fixo no rodapé do layout, deves usar um `RelativeLayout`, que seria a sugestão do David. É possível ajustar sua `ListView` para que ela não fique abaixo do botão.

Comment: PERFEITO! Agora como que eu customizo esse botão? @acklay

Comment: @LucasCharles isso já é outra pergunta. Sugiro que verifique se há aqui no stackoverflow formas de customizar um botão programaticamente. Caso não haja, você pode fazer uma nova pergunta. Se houver mais alguma dúvida a respeito dessa pergunta, podes fazer aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona o botão como um item da ListView, você poderá detectar quando o botão foi clicado de duas formas vendo "int id" e "int position" de onItemClick, ou poderá setar "setOnClickListener" no botão.

Exemplo básico:

```
ListView listView = new ListView(context);

Button button = new Button(context);

button.setText("Enviar");

button.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
));

/* Opção 1: Evento diretamente no botao */
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        /*[...]*/
    }
});

listView.addView(button);

/* Opção 2: Detectar se o item clicado é o botão */
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
});
```

Fiz o exemplo programaticamente sem xml apenas para que possa entender

Comment: E como eu implemento button.setLayoutParams/*[...]*/? @Mystic teria como me dar um exemplo com o XML? Por favor?

Comment: @LucasCharles Adicionei texto no botão e os parâmetros, me diga como está adicionando itens nessa ListView

Comment: Editei la como eu estou adicionando itens na minha lista. Não consigo adicionar apenas o botão. Ele pede outros parâmetros.

Answer (score 0):

tu pode fazer outra abordagem também.
Demarcando para sua ListView terminar antes do Buttom e usando um scrollView para exibir o conteudo completo da lista, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttom">
    </ListView>

    <Buttom
        android:id="@+id/buttom"
        android:text="Teste"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </Buttom>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Nesse exemplo o botão ficará abaixo da tua lista, mas ela irá precisar de um scroll para ser vista por inteira, outra abordagem é ter um scroll na tela inteira e deixar o ListView com tamanho dos conteúdos, ficamdo mais ou menos assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/buttom">
            </ListView>

            <Buttom
                android:id="@+id/buttom"
                android:text="Teste"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
            </Buttom>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fora esses pode colocar como último elemento da tua ListView o botão, mas isso tu não vai conseguir fazer direto no xml, é mais fácil seguir o exemplo do amigo Mystic.